# Segmentation fault when trying to copy elements of a string (C)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to work on a problem for school which requires me to reverse a string in place (among other things..). I have been struggling with this for awhile and am out of ideas.. here is my code:

```
void strRev(char*s)
{
    int i = 0;
    int length = strlen(s);
    char*rev = (char*)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));

    strcpy(rev,s);

    for(i;i<length;i++)
        s[i] = rev[length - 1 - i];

    printf("%s    %s",rev,s);
}

int main()
{
    char * test = "hello";
    strRev(test);
}
```

when I step through in Visual Studio, it hangs when it reaches the line inside the for loop. Unix gives me a segmentation fault. I know this must be something simple I'm missing, but I'm out of ideas and none of the answers online are helping.. And I'm running out of time.. Someone please enlighten me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you *do* use `malloc()` you must remember to `free()` the pointer it returned before returning from the function (and losing the pointer).

Comment: thanks.. I changed the declaration of test as described above and it works now.. My instructor has specifically taught us that a string may be declared either way, he certainly failed to mention that the first creates a pointer to a literal vs. an array that can be modified.. I'll be sure and bring it up tomorrow in class :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code doesn't do it in place (else you wouldn't use malloc, also why are you using sizeof(char)?).

Try this:

```
void strRev(char*s)
{
    int i, len;
    char tmp;
    len = strlen(s);
    for(i = 0; i < (len >> 1); ++i)
    {
       tmp = s[len - 1 - i];
       s[len - 1 - i] = s[i];
       s[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

And then modify you main() as the comments suggest.

Comment: @Seth Bergman: this answer contains something smart you will most likely have to explain to your teacher.

Comment: thanks good answer.. I only use malloc because that is a current lesson coinciding with the assignment, so I assume that's what they had in mind.. (the assignments are handed down from a different instructor, and are not worded very well..)

Comment: also, why wouldn't I use sizeof(char)? theoretically, couldn't that be a different size on some system somewhere? or is it always the same?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with sizeof(char).  It's a mistake to assume that a `char` is only 1 byte in length.

Answer (score 1):

`test` points to statically allocated buffer which must not be modified. And you do modify it by assigning `s[i]=rev[...]`. This causes segfault.

I think you wanted to write `rev[i]=s[...]`.

If you need to do it in place then allocate memory for `"hello"` dynamically (`strdup`) or on stack.